# I have a PDF containing two pages. How can I write text in second page using pdfbox 2.0.26?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a PDF file that contains two pages. I had write text in first page, now I want to write text in second page, but text is not showing in second page.

How can I write in both first and second page at the same time?

```
PDDocument pdfdoc = PDDocument.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/test.pdf"));
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(pdfdoc, pdfdoc.getPage(0), PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, 0);
contentStream.setFont(PDType0Font.load(pdfdoc, new File(getClass().getResource("/fonts/...").getPath())), 12);
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(125, 600);
contentStream.showText(letter_number.getValue());
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
pdfdoc.close();
```

Comment: Please post the current code and mention the version. Obviously you managed to write on the first page so there's only one digit to change.

Comment: Thanks ! i have posted the current version and the code...?

Comment: What happens when you replace `pdfdoc.getPage(0)` with `pdfdoc.getPage(1)`?

Comment: tried but doesn't work...

Comment: It works when writing text to pdf in either page index 0 or 1,,but i need to write text in both page at the same time.

Comment: Why not duplicate the code that starts with `PDPageContentStream` and ends with `contentStream.close();` and modify the page number? Create the font outside, you can reuse it. If that doesn't work, please share the result PDF.

Comment: Btw your font loading won't work outside of the IDE. Use `getResourceAsStream` and if you use maven, be careful to turn off resource filtering for the font.

Comment: @IshworSubedi *"i need to write text in both page at the same time"* - each page has its own collection of content streams. While you theoretically could add the same stream to multiple pages, that only would complicate matters as you'd also keep the resources of those pages in sync. You also could create a form Xobject and show it on both pages. But if there is only a small amount of text, the easiest approach is adding the text to both pages in separate content streams as proposed by Tilman.